# Inserts don't appear to be happening

Tags: python, mysql, gevent

I'm using gevent with gevent-mysql (I also used pymysql to the same effect). It does selects just fine but no matter what I do I can't get it to run an insert. I'm out of ideas.

```
conn = geventmysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', db='content')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into placement (placement_name, some_id) values ('static', 1)")
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Is there an error message, or does the data just not appear when you do a select?

Comment: Also, what engine are you using for the `placement` table?

Comment: @Chris, no there is no error. It just doesn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a transactional storage engine (like InnoDB), you should check the value of the `autocommit` variable: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit

If it is `0`, you need to commit your transactions, either using a built in `commit()` method or an `execute("COMMIT")` call.

Comment: winner winner. That was it. So, it's not autocommiting (someone else mentioned being able to set a flag) Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

If geventmysql works like the rest of the python DB APIs, you need to call commit in order to commit any changes to the database. Unless geventmysql

Comment: This is not the case with geventmysql or pymysql, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), everything is implicitly a transaction. If you close the connection without committing, it gets rolled back. Do this:

```
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```